# Javascript how to run some code after a forEach completes executing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

So I want to turn my "loading" gif on and off with `ng-show`. I would specifically like to turn it off after my script is done loading the array through a `forEach`.

How do I run code when the `forEach` completes its entire cycle". Something similar to a `.then()`, but for `for` loops

```
function selectAll(bool) {
  vm.selectAllSpinner = true;
  vm.practicesLeftCol = [];
  if(bool === true){
    vm.practices.forEach(function(practice){
      practice.selected = true;
      vm.practicesLeftCol.push(practice)
    })
    I want this after the foreach ->vm.selectAllSpinner = false;

  } else if (bool === false){
    vm.practices.forEach(function(practice){
      practice.selected = false;
      vm.practicesLeftCol = [];
    })
    I want this after the foreach ->vm.selectAllSpinner = false;

  }
```

Comment: Since the computations done is `forEach` loop are trivial, you will not even see the spinner show up. I am thinking the spinner shows up but is not visible to the naked eye.

Comment: no, it does not - angular needs to fire digest cycle to show the spinner and it does that after its value is again set to false

Answer (score -1):

So `forEach` isn't asynchronous. As such, you could literally just write:

```
function selectAll(bool) {
          vm.selectAllSpinner = true;
          vm.practicesLeftCol = [];
          if(bool === true){
            vm.practices.forEach(function(practice){
              practice.selected = true;
              vm.practicesLeftCol.push(practice)
            })
          } else if (bool === false){
            vm.practices.forEach(function(practice){
              practice.selected = false;
              vm.practicesLeftCol = [];
            })
          }
    vm.selectAllSpinner = false;
}
```

Having said that, I think the code could be cleaned up in general to be more like so:

```
  function selectAll(bool) {
    vm.selectAllSpinner = true;
    vm.practicesLeftCol = [];
    if (bool) {
      vm.practicesLeftCol = vm.practices.reduce(function(memo, practice) {
        practice.selected = true;
        memo.push(practice);
        return memo;
      }, []);
    }
   vm.selectAllSpinner = false; 
}
```

Again, neither `reduce` nor `forEach` are asynchronous, so this should just kinda work...

Comment: it will not work as angular has to fire the digest cycle and when it does `selectAllSpinner` will be false again

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work unfortunately. It fires twice before the `if` statements that contain `forEach` loops. Probably due to what @pwolaq said

Comment: I don't see how angular is particularly relevant here? I don't see a call to $scope, we're setting things on a global variable of some sort instead...

Comment: yes but spinner is displayed based on this variable via ng-show directive

Comment: Ah good point. I may be dense, but why not just store vm on $scope? @IWI

Comment: would that make a difference? @AbrahamP --> it didnt make a difference

Answer (score -2):

In Javascript, use the semicolon (`;`) delimiter, optionally followed by a newline, to append a command to a previous command.  Thus

```
function selectAll(bool) {
    vm.selectAllSpinner = true;
    vm.practicesLeftCol = [];
    if(bool === true){
        vm.practices.forEach(function(practice){
            practice.selected = true;
            vm.practicesLeftCol.push(practice)
        });
        vm.selectAllSpinner = false;  //<---
    } else if (bool === false) {
        vm.practices.forEach(function(practice){
            practice.selected = false;
            vm.practicesLeftCol = [];
        });
        vm.selectAllSpinner = false; //<---
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just a convention. Line terminators cause automatic semicolon insertion sometimes

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately forEach does not have a callback - but you could do something like this:

```
  if(bool === true){
        vm.practices.forEach(function(practice){
          practice.selected = true;
          vm.practicesLeftCol.push(practice);
           items++;
           if(items === your_array.length) {
             vm.selectAllSpinner = false;
           }
        })

      }
```

Comment: javascript runs in single thread (mostly), you should just put your code after forEach call...